# Recall approval process by apex

Tags: apex, approval-process

I am attempting to recall an approval process with the following Apex code:

```
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest pwr = new
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();  pwr.setAction('Removed');
pwr.setWorkItemId(workItems[0].id);
Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(pwr);
```

It works fine when I run it as an administrator or when the user running it is the submitter of the approval process.

But it doesn't work for any other users; I get this error:

> Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

How can I make this work for any user?

To complete my question, I created a visualforce page to add a custom button on the object page layout calling the apex method below ManageButton.documentCustomGetApprovalProcess

```
public without sharing class ManageButton 
{
    // Constructor
    public ManageButton(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
    {
    }

    /**
     * method used by the Get Approval Process button
     */   
    public PageReference documentCustomGetApprovalProcess()
    { 
        string docId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        ProcessInstanceWorkitem[] workItems = [
             SELECT Id
               FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem 
              WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :docId
                AND ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'];

        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest pwr = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        pwr.setAction('Removed');
        pwr.setWorkItemId(workItems[0].id);
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(pwr);

        // Redirect the user back to the original page
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + docId);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

Even specifing "without sharing" on the class I have the error I mentioned.

Comment: Have the code that is getting called in a class that executes 'without sharing'.

Comment: Hello, I tried this but it has no impact. I fould the link [link](https://force746.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/apex-controller-class-without-sharing-in-practice/) stipulating the without sharing has no impact on this error.

Comment: The link you posted there, actually says it solved this error.  In my experience, it has solved it as well.

Comment: You are right the link says it should work adding without sharing. I tried it and I still have the issue.

Comment: You should edit your question with that code instead of placing it in comments.

Comment: For sure, it's my first question, I didn't know we can edit the question.

Answer (score 10):

By design, Approval Processes only allow either a System Administrator and/or the Initial Submitter to recall the submission.

Per Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_create_submitters.htm&language=en_US&type=0):

[image]

**However**, to answer your question *How can I make this work for any user?* you will need your Apex code to change the **context user** to be a System Administrator.

One way to achieve this is by using [Apex Email Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm) and sending an email to its service address from your Apex code. Email Services let you specify a context user that the code will run under and so in **that** apex code you can try performing your recall action.

Side note, I've used this Apex Email Service technique to run code as a specific user in other projects like [Salesforce Chatter Bot for Feeds](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/salesforce-chatter-bot-feeds).

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea that.

Answer (score 3):

A more modern approach (though similar in principle to Doug's answer) is to use Platform Events.

In my code I checked the approval and fired like this:

```
if(thisApprovalRequest.approvalAction == 'Removed' && thisWorkItem.ActorId == thisUserId && thisWorkItem.ProcessInstance.SubmittedById != thisUserId) {
    approvalRecalls.add(new Approval_Recall__e(
            Process_Instance_Work_Item_Id__c = thisWorkItem.Id,
            Comment__c = thisApprovalRequest.comment
    ));
}
```

...

```
EventBus.publish(approvalRecalls);
```

Then, an Apex Platform Event trigger can do the recall. Since it runs as Automated Process User, it has the same sort of admin permission to do the recall

Comment: For the record I tried this approach. The Platform Event runs as Automated Process but unfortunately hits the same issue:



```Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []```

Comment: I can't really tell why that didn't work for you, but I have this working in a production org, so it definitely *can* work

Comment: This approach worked great for me. Thank you @Aidan!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Doug suggestion below is one way to achieve recall of an approval process without compromising security or being the submitter.

**Code Excerpt:**

```
global virtual with sharing class ID_Item extends cms.ContentTemplateController implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler  {

...       

@RemoteAction
global static Map<String, Object> mApprovalRecallAction(String sContentID, String sName) {
    System.debug('>>> ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...)');

    ...

    // submitter is the person recalling, so we have permission to do so (otherwise we need to be an admin: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iY1aAAE)
    if (oApproval.CreatedById == UserInfo.getUserId()) {        
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest oPWR = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest(); 
        oPWR.setComments('Recalled by `' + oApproval.CreatedBy.Name + '`');
        oPWR.setAction('Removed');
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { // can't seem to create ProcessInstanceWorkItem records in tests
            oPWR.setWorkItemId(oWorkItemList[0].id);
            Approval.ProcessResult oPR = Approval.process(oPWR);
        }

        // Next the approval process needs to have a recalled action that sets `cms__Approval__c.Status = 'Recalled'` which is levraged by OrchestraCMS - but just incase these were deleted we are changing the status in apex as well
        oApproval.cms__Status__c = 'Recalled';
        oApproval.Content_Status__c = 'Recalled';
        update oApproval;
        System.debug('=== ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...): `JSON.serialize(oPWR)=' + JSON.serialize(oPWR) + '`');
        return new Map<String, Object>{'bSuccess' => true, 'sPWR' => JSON.serialize(oPWR)};
    }
    // we assume `this.bApprovalRecalVisible` did our security checks  
    else {
        // we leverage the functionality that an email service allows us to run under a adming user
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage oMessage = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        try {
            // find our email service to use, as convention we prefixed it with class name 
            EmailServicesAddress oEmailServiceAddress = [
                SELECT e.SystemModstamp, e.RunAsUserId, e.LocalPart, e.LastModifiedDate, e.LastModifiedById, e.IsActive, e.Id, e.FunctionId, e.EmailDomainName, e.CreatedDate, e.CreatedById, e.AuthorizedSenders 
                FROM EmailServicesAddress e
                WHERE e.IsActive = true AND e.LocalPart LIKE 'ID_Item%' // `LIKE` is case-insensetive, so we keep capitialization same as class name as it's easier for search and replace 
                ].get(0); 
            oMessage.toAddresses = new String[] {
                oEmailServiceAddress.LocalPart + '@' + oEmailServiceAddress.EmailDomainName
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('=== ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...): ERROR: no email service setup, `e' + String.valueOf(e) + '`');
            return new Map<String, Object>{'bSuccess' => true, 'e' => JSON.serialize('ERROR: no email service setup, `e' + String.valueOf(e) + '`')};
        }
        Map<String, Object> oParameterMap = new Map<String, Object>{'sAction' => 'mApprovalRecallActionWithAdminPermissions', 'sApprovalID' => oApproval.Id};
        oMessage.subject = '=== ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...): `JSON.serialize(oParameterMap)=' + JSON.serialize(oParameterMap) + '`'; // using subject is not safe because SF can modify it sometimes (ex. prefixing `Sandbox`  
        oMessage.plainTextBody = JSON.serialize(oParameterMap);
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] oResults = Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {oMessage});

        System.debug('=== ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...): `oResults' + String.valueOf(oResults) + '`');

        System.debug('<<< ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...)');
        if (oResults[0].success) {
            return new Map<String, Object>{'bSuccess' => true, 'oResults' => JSON.serialize(String.valueOf(oResults))};
        } else {
            return new Map<String, Object>{'bSuccess' => false, 'oResults' => JSON.serialize(String.valueOf(oResults))};
        }
    }       
}


global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail oInboundEmail, Messaging.InboundEnvelope oInboundEnvelope){
    System.debug('>>> ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...)');
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult oInboundEmailResult = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

    Map<String,Object> oParameterMap = new Map<String, Object>{'sAction' => 'UNKNOWN'};
    try {
        oParameterMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(oInboundEmail.plainTextBody); 
        // expected string input format is "{'sAction': 'fooBar', 'sApprovalID': 'foo', ...}"
    } 
    catch (QueryException e) {
        System.debug('=== ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...): ERROR: `e=' + e + '`');
        System.debug('<<< ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...)');
        return oInboundEmailResult;
    }
    try {
        if (oParameterMap.get('sAction') == 'mApprovalRecallActionWithAdminPermissions') {
            String sApprovalID = (String)oParameterMap.get('sApprovalID');
            cms__Approval__c oApproval = [Select ID, c.cms__Content__c FROM cms__Approval__c c WHERE c.Id = :sApprovalID].get(0);
            List<ProcessInstanceWorkItem> oWorkItemList = [Select ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId, ActorId From ProcessInstanceWorkitem where ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :oApproval.ID];

            //System.debug(oWorkItemList[0]);
            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest oPWR = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest(); 
            oPWR.setComments('Recalled by `' + oInboundEnvelope.fromAddress + '`');
            oPWR.setAction('Reject');

            if (Test.isRunningTest() == false) {
                oPWR.setWorkItemId(oWorkItemList[0].id);
                Approval.ProcessResult oPR = Approval.process(oPWR);
            }

        }

    }
    catch (QueryException e) {
         System.debug('=== ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...): ERROR: `e=' + e + '`');
    }

    oInboundEmailResult.success = true;
    System.debug('<<< ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...)');
    return oInboundEmailResult;
}

...
```

}

Comment: usually answers should have the system.debug lines removed

Answer (score 0):

Older thread but in case it helps others. I was able to get this working by running a flow as system and calling an apex action. Seemed cleaner than creating a platform event.

Edit: This approach will only work if the user initiating the flow has the modify all permission on the object that is being approved.